# how to apply ngfor for non li elements?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-directives, ngfor

I am trying  loop a set of data once the condition is satisfied ,I am displaying a label but its adding space in front of the label because of div that I am using for ngfor. How do I achieve displaying text without having a space in front of it.below is the sample that I am trying

```
'<div  *ngFor="let rows of list"   >

     <label  *ngIf="list.name == 'test'"  >Confirm </label>
      <strong>{{list.name}}</strong> 


    <label *ngIf="rows.name != 'test' ">dont Confirm
 <strong>{{list.name}}</strong> 
</label>
</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-container` or use css to remove the spacing of the div :)

Comment: @yacky, then the issue is not with `div`. Put up a stackblitz and we can take a look

Comment: @yacky,,,,,, :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  *ngFor="let rows of list"   >

 <label  *ngIf="list.name == 'test'"  >Confirm </label>
```

There must be an error in your example, in a ngFor list **must** be an array. How can an array have a name-property? The name of the variable holding the array is "list". Also, I would not name "rows" like that, it is confusing, just name it "row".

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngFor